# Etymology of the word 'sin'

Tags: etymology

In the Oxford English Dictionary of 1989, Vol. VII. under the verb 'sin' it lists the earliest recorded use of the word as from circa 825 AD. The word 'sin' was written then as 'syngian'. If the Latin suffix 'ian' means: of or belonging to, how does the verb sin derive from syng or sing which could be interpreted as a substantive or a separate entity?

Comment: The etymology given is  "Old English syngian < *sunigôjan, < *sunjō", and doesn't mention Latin anywhere in it.

Comment: You're right that most of those who could write were cleric, schooled in Latin; and that since the Norman conquest a great deal of Latin vocabulary has entered English, either directly or through French. But there was much less Latin borrowing before 1066. There is no reason to suppose any Latin influence in that word.

Answer (score 3):

The suffix `-ian` in Old English is unrelated to the Latin suffix; Old English doesn't have that many Latin elements. It on the other hand goes back to Proto-Germanic `-(i)janą` which formed the class 1 and some 3 weak verbs which, besides the precursor of `syngian` included words such as `*dōmijaną *kussijaną *nistijaną`. The suffix `-ian` has an identical cognate in Old Saxon.

Edit: simply speaking, the `-ian` suffix in Old English at the ends of verb infinitives has nothing to do with the Latin `-ian` suffix. The `-ian` suffix in Old English is one of the more frequent endings of regular verbs. The origin of `syngian` is simply explained as the descendant of `*sundigōjaną` in Proto-Germanic as a derivation of `*sundi-` (from `*sundijō`) + `*-gō(?)` (some sort of derivational suffix, possibly) + `*-janą` (weak verb ending).

Comment: Darkgamma hasn't mentioned that _-ian_ was one of the regular forms of the infinitive in Old English (corresponding to _-en_ in German).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15210/discussion-between-duane-t-bentz-and-darkgamma).

Comment: @Darkgamma: Sunigojan from the OED, vol. XV, p.505. I divided this word up in elements as 'sun/ig/ojan. I found in "A Concise Anglo-Saxon Dictionary" by Hall of 1916 that 'ig'= ic or I, finding no suffix yet of the same spelling. Can you comment also on the list of derivatives to sin in the OED, that among them is listed the Dutch 'zondigen', the Dutch language being also of the West Germanic Group. I ask this because in the A.S. Dictionary there isn't any 'z' words listed & probably not coming into use until after 1100 AD. Does zondigen from Dutch predate the 12th Century?

Comment: Such a division doesn't make sense. The "i" in that "ig" element was part of `*sundijō` (sin) and the "g" of the element was part of  the suffix `*-gō`. A list of derivatives that includes a word in a foreign language that is known to have cognates in other languages that certainly can't have had it borrowed automatically disqualifies the list. Derivatives are within one language, not across languages if the languages hadn't borrowed them from one another. Dutch "zondigen" certainly predates the 12th century.

Comment: @Darkgamma: When did 'z' words first appear in Germanic languages? If they didn't appear until after the 12th century then I am perplexed by the Dutch 'zondigen' as listed in the derivatives from the OED. Does this peculiarity have possibilities as a substratum of language?

Comment: Well, "z" appeared in Germanic at about the time when Germanic itself came into being: Proto-Germanic had /*z/. As for Dutch z-initial words, they came into being around the tenth or eleventh century. They're from a wider trend of voicing fricatives: the shift made voiceless fricatives voiced at the beginning of syllables. This also happened in German although spelling doesn't quite reflect it (German /z/ is written with "s", and the /v/ that came from /f/ has in the meanwhile become /f/ again)

Comment: @Darkgamma: But the ancient Germans had no written language until after they were Christianized in the 7th century. They were considered nomadic barbarians before by the more advanced nations they came into contact with. What you are saying though is that such Anglo-Saxon words written as: sind, sinder and sindon could have been pronounced as zind, zinder or zindon. If this is true I can see a connection to the Akkadian ZNN, Ugaritic ZN, Aramaic ZNH, ZNY, and Hebrew itself all of which are older languages. Refer to: Book Notes: The Hebrew Harlot- A Guest Review by Carly Crouch on the web.

Comment: Writing has nothing to do with the sound system. You're rather misinformed, if I can so say. There is no connection between Semitic and English.

Comment: @Darkgamma- To be learned is good but many times those with extensive educations "can't see the trees for the forest" meaning its possible to be too broad. Linguistic theory can be too broad to see the simple solution. The ancient Germans/Anglo-Saxons came from somewhere and I believe certain parts of there language survived from their roots. What does the academic society believe through their theories is the ancestry of the Germans/Anglo-Saxons? Surely they have studied this.

Comment: Yes, they have! Every bit of scientific proof points to absolutely no connection to the Semites. While Semitic languages come from the Afro-Asiatic language family, the Germans and Anglo-Saxons belong to the Germanic family of languages, which is part of the Centum subclade of the Indo-European language family. While the AAs. family came from Africa, the IE family came from somewhere either in eastern Ukraine or southwestern Russia. No connection at all.

Comment: Anglo-Saxon: s(z)in, by comparative method, relates to the Semitic zn, znn, znh, zny, or znut in phonetics.

Comment: To Whom it may concern, Its been several days since I last checked this site and frankly I was shocked that the powers to be edited out most of my final comment. I photocopied this entire site several days ago and I know what I said. I question now the motives behind the editing which to me is lacking in integrity. I expected more from scholars than that.

Comment: In response to your earlier comment, there wasn't such a thing as Anglo-Saxon <sin>, there was only maybe Old English <sīn>, a reflexive pronoun. It wasn't ever pronounced with /z/. Using the comparative method involves more than one correspondence (and even a correct one, on top of that). There is quite a lot more to be said, but I honestly have no energy to argue knowing that arguing is pointless and you won't be convinced.

Comment: @Darkgamma- I have no desire to argue either. I was only going by what you said earlier as I chose to trust scholars of Modern English. I study the past and so reflexive pronouns didn't even exist in the 10th century. That is strictly a modern English term and I am trying to learn about language as it was understood centuries ago in its simplicity. To my knowledge from history Old English was later called Anglo-Saxon because of political expediency. I suggest you read from the 1947 Websters International English Dictionary in its opening pages before the Socialist agenda took hold in America.

Comment: Reflexive pronouns *did* exist, I'm not sure what you're basing your claim off. They're the only consistent third person form in Latin ("suus/sua/suum" and "suī/sibi/sēsē/sēsē), they're present in Slavic ("svoj/svoja/svoje" and "sebe/se"), and also almost unchanged across Germanic: German "sein/seine/sein" and "sich", Icelandic "sinn/sín/sitt" and "sig". That proves to something deeper than the tenth century.

Comment: @Darkgamma- Can you produce a tenth century document wherein the author specifically mentions the term 'reflexive pronoun'? I agree that in modern terminology all words are designated by category but in ancient times did they use the same terms we use today? That's what I was referring to and should have been more specific. Concerning the 's' & 'z' question I am reading an older book wherein the author(a scholar from Yale) declared that the 'z' in Old English sounds like 'ts'. This is very confusing as I remember your own declaration earlier. 'ts or tz' can be associated with Hebrew also.

Comment: They didn't use the term "reflexive pronoun", but they used the pronouns themselves. Concerning Old English <z>, I said nothing about it; I was talking about Dutch and Saxon <z>

Comment: @Darkgamma- Can you tell me how the letter 'S' appears as a /surd/ or a /sonant/ while providing a couple of examples in Old English words. Thank you

Comment: @DuaneT.Bentz, uh could you explain the terms?

Comment: @Darkgamma- Surd= voiceless sound; sonant= voiced sound; please provide a couple of examples from Old English words bearing the letter 'S' for me. I need your expertise in phonetics here.

Comment: @DuaneT.Bentz, this is better explained using Wikipedia; just look up Old English phonology. What little there is on consonants is all you need since there isn't much more pertaining to /s/